# What does "Electronic Ready" mean on a Giant Frame?

Tags: cyclocross, electronics

I just purchased a 2014 Giant TCX SLR 2, and noticed in the spec sheet that the frame is "Electronic Ready"

What does this mean?

http://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-ca/bikes/model/tcx.slr.2/17669/73500/#specifications

I was hoping this would mean ready for a speed/cadence sensor but that seems to be "RideSense ready" in terms of Giant lingo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on comparison with the Giant Defy Advanced line, it seems to mean that you can run an electronic drivetrain (such as Shimano Di2 parts) - you have to mount things like a battery in order for the shifters to work and what not, so the frame will need to have the wiring harnesses and battery pack mounted.

This [link](http://www.cyclingnews.com/features/photos/giant-2012-road-launch/179020) shows the TCR line in 2012 with this done.

What does an electronic drive train mean for most people? Likely, just an emptier wallet. But thats a different question all together.